# Set networking so as to turn Wi-Fi on/off when X process is started/interrupted (Linux)

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, automation

My aim is to set (through scripts/daemons/whatever piece of software might help) my laptop networking so as to turn on automatically when I start software X (e.g. Firefox), and automatically turn off once that software has been closed/terminated.
(even more ambitious, setting 2 softwares X and Y as switches, if possible)
Any contribution will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Simplest way: write a script that wraps calling of X, adjusts networking before calling it, monitors X for termination, and adjusts networking back. Call script instead of X. Doesn't work if you plan to use several instances of X simultaneously.  In case this is an XY question: If you want to give Firefox a different networking environment, you can also call it inside a network namespace that's properly set up.

Comment: Thank you very much @dirkt!  If you could write an example of script code as an answer, that would be it for me. I am using elementary OS, so my base is Ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commands for stopping and starting networking are :

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking { stop | start }
sudo nmcli { networking | radio } { on | off }
```

Or for just one particular network interface :

```
sudo ifdown ethX
sudo ifup ethX
```

The last one may have a problem if your router is not in
`/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-ethX`, then it may not be completely deleted/added by the ifup/ifdown scripts.
For example, to delete you may also need to use :

```
route del default ethX
```

After launching firefox, to wait for it to finish you can use the
[wait command](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/uwait.htm)
with or without parameters.

This is the script which worked for the poster :

```
nmcli radio wifi on
sleep 2
firefox
nmcli radio wifi off
```

Sleep is done with the number of seconds to wait before the network stabilizes,
empirically tested.

You should also ensure that the network is disabled after boot.

Comment: thank you very much! I have made a couple of adjustments to your script, and it works exactly as intended. This is the final result

Comment: nmcli radio wifi on  /
sleep 2  /
firefox  /
wait firefox  /
nmcli radio wifi off

Comment: as soon as you have updated your answer, I'll award you the bounty points!

Comment: Done as requested.

Comment: `firefox` doesn't return until it's closed, so you don't need `wait`. moreover, `wait: \`firefox': not a pid or valid job spec`.

Comment: I was wondering on which Linux distribution `wait firefox` worked ... But `wait` doesn't hurt here, just in case.

Comment: My fault for not realizing! "wait" can totally be omitted, has no job in there!!

Comment: Well, in that case, out it goes!